# Overcoming erasure case study; currying Maps

Tags: scala

I have been struggling with the following Scala code

```
def curry[A,B,C,U](m: Map[(A,B,C),U], a: A): Map[(B,C),U] = m.collect { case ((aa,b,c),v) if aa == a => (b,c) -> v }
def curry[A,B,C,U](m: Map[(A,B,C),U], b: B): Map[(A,C),U] = m.collect { case ((a,bb,c),v) if bb == b => (a,c) -> v }
```

I cannot compile this as both functions are the same after Erasure, and I have to resort to terrible workarounds (like `curry1`, `curry2`, `curry12` etc.)

> Error: double definition:
>   def curry[A, B, C, U](m: Map[(A, B, C),U], a: A): Map[(B, C),U] at line 152 and
>   def curry[A, B, C, U](m: Map[(A, B, C),U], b: B): Map[(A, C),U] at line 153
>   have same type after erasure: (m: scala.collection.immutable.Map, a: Object)scala.collection.immutable.Map
>     def curry[A,B,C,U](m: Map[(A,B,C),U], b: B): Map[(A,C),U] = m.collect { case ((a,bb,c),v) if bb == b => (a,c) -> v }

Is there a way to make this work? Dire situations allow for dire solutions (aka reflection and TypeTags maybe?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround:

```
def curry[A,B,C,U](m: Map[(A,B,C),U], a: A): Map[(B,C),U] = m.collect { case ((aa,b,c),v) if aa == a => (b,c) -> v }
def curry[A,B,C,U](m: Map[(A,B,C),U], b: B, dummy: Int = 0): Map[(A,C),U] = m.collect { case ((a,bb,c),v) if bb == b => (a,c) -> v }
```

Or:

```
def curry[A,B,C,U](m: Map[(A,B,C),U], a: A): Map[(B,C),U] = m.collect { case ((aa,b,c),v) if aa == a => (b,c) -> v }
def curry[A,B,C,U](m: Map[(A,B,C),U], b: B)(implicit d: DummyImplicit): Map[(A,C),U] = m.collect { case ((a,bb,c),v) if bb == b => (a,c) -> v }
```

Comment: Is the first one not giving you the error “Overloaded definition with defaults?”

Comment: @rausted the first one works in Scala 3.0 a.k.a dotty